# .htaccess rewrite to allow directory or no directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule that adds a .php extension to urls.

Url's entered look like this : `http://localhost/Home`

Url's read look like this : `http://localhost/home.php`

The problem i'm having is that some urls may look likes this:

`http://localhost/sub/123`

I should explain, this isn't actually a subdirectory. The `sub` part is the file and the `123` is used as a get variable. It looks cleaner this way.

If this happens you get a 500 error;

Here's what it is at the moment

```
#add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And here's what i've tried but doesn't work.

```
#add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)|(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this to solve your problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(phpscripts|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?:/(.*?|))?/?$ /$1.php?$2 [L]
```

Comment: Okay new problem. How can I only use this rule if the subfolder is `gig`. This works perfectly for what I asked but now have encountered a new problem which I overlooked. There are subfolders that are accessed by javascript

Comment: So you want to apply above rules only for URIs such as '/gig/User` or `/gig/about` ?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively not apply the rule for anything in phpscripts or js folder. Actually the alternative would be better

Comment: Ok just for my understanding are your JS files using relative paths. Can you try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before `-d` condition above to see if that helps. If you're using relative paths then I would suggest using absolute paths i.e. starting with `/` or `http://`

Comment: Okay well I have added that but hasn't had an effect. Is there just a simple rule where I could exclude `phpscripts` and `js` from the rule?